# Why Google not offering to save password for Jetpack Compose Text Field?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I had refactored a login flow from XML to Compose.

The old login flow, after logging in successfully, would have Google suggest to save your password.

[image]

However, since I refactored it, it doesn't do this anymore.

The old XML layout just used a `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`. The new composable is just an `OutlinedTextField` with some keyboard options.

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    android:hint="@string/password">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```kotlin
OutlinedTextField(
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
    )
)
```

Why is Google not suggesting to save the password? Both old and new code was run on the same emulator, which has auto fill services enabled.

Answer (score 3):

There is [limited autofill support in Compose UI 1.0.x](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176949051). With luck, this situation will improve in the coming years.